# PYTHON parameter passing with lists

Tags: python, list, parameter-passing

When passing a parameter into my function, it will not recognize the list and output the string.

The game is called pass the pigs, and it is required to output a state that the pig lands on.

I know in places that the code is inefficient, though this is due to the fact that I have been trying different methods that have no succeeded :(

Thanks in advance for any help!

Here is code:

```
norolls = int(input("Enter the number of rolls: "))
counter = 0

def roll(nothrows,counter):
    rollList = []
    while counter < nothrows:
        rollrand = randint(0,100)
        rollList.append(rollrand)
        counter = (counter + 1)
    return rollList

rollList = roll(norolls,counter)
rollList = list(map(int, rollList))
listlen = len(rollList)    

def rollout(List, listpos, ListLen):
    listpos = 0
    for x in range(ListLen):
        if List[listpos] == 1< 35:
            print("Pink")
        elif List[listpos] == 35 < 65:
            print("Dot")
        elif List[listpos] == 65< 85:
            print("Razorback")
        elif List[listpos] == 85 < 95:
            print("Trotter")
        elif List[listpos] == 95 < 99:
            print("Snouter")
        else:
            List[listpos] == 99 < 100
            print("Leaning Jewler")
        listpos = (listpos + 1)


rollout(rollList, counter, listlen)
```

Comment: I don't understand the *if ... == x < y* contruct; in any case the first comparison will return 0 or 1 and this is smaller than all your y constants as 35, 65....

Comment: ¯|_(ツ)_/¯ umm not sure

Comment: @guidot: not quite.  `a == b < c` isn't parsed as `(a==b) < c`, it's `(a == b) and (b < c)`, as this is a chained comparison.  Still not what's intended, of course. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want `if List[listpos] == 1< 35` to mean `List[listpos]` is between 1 and 35, with 35 not being included.
The way to write that is:

```
if 1 <= List[listpos] < 35:
```

But, in your case, you don't really need a 3 level condition, since the only the first true if statement will run. So, you can just simply do:

```
if List[listpos] < 35:
    print("Pink")
elif List[listpos] < 65:
    ...
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I have too low reputation to comment, but I'm going to try and clarify the code a little and give my answer.

For starters, one thing you should know is that `list` is a reserved name, so I don't recommend passing it as an argument to any function. You should be passing `rollList` to `rollout()`, since that is the list that you are creating. The way to pass a list as an argument is like this:

`list_name = [1,2,3,4,5]`

`def function_name(myList=[]):
   for x in myList:
      print x`

`function_name(list_name)`

Note the `myList=[]` in the function definition.

I would also get rid of `counter` and `listlen` as arguments, since you are setting counter to 0 at the beginning of the function, and `listlen` can be found with the `len()` function.

Secondly, for your equality statements, type them in like this:

`if list_name[listpos] >= 1 and list_name[listpos] < 35`

I'm sure there's a shorter way to do it, but this would help you visualize it as a range of values.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are only 100 possible rolls (you do not assign an interpretation to 0) there is an alternative approach: replace the if-elif-else change with a lookup table mapping rolls to names.  The code below does this.  It also creates a list of rolls with a list comprehension.

```
from random import randint

rollmap = [None]
for sublist in (35*['Pink'], 30*['Dot'], 20*['Razorback'],
                10*['Trotter'], 4*['Snouter'], 1*['Leaning Jewler']):
    rollmap.extend(sublist)

n = int(input("Enter the number of rolls: "))
rolls = [randint(1, len(rollmap-1)) for i in range(n)]
for roll in rolls:
    print(rollmap[roll])
```